# Porting addon from Odoo 9 to Odoo 10 - ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'account.tax'

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

While trying to reuse this Odoo 9 addon https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/purchase_recurring_orders/ | [github code](https://github.com/CybroOdoo/CybroAddons/tree/9.0/purchase_recurring_orders) to Odoo 10, I am facing the following issue:

```py
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/custom_addons/purchase_recurring_orders/models/recurring_orders.py", line 310, in generate_initial_order
order = self.create_order(self.start_date, agreement_lines)
...
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'account.tax'
```

Full error can be seen here:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 889, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/custom_addons/purchase_recurring_orders/models/recurring_orders.py", line 310, in generate_initial_order
    order = self.create_order(self.start_date, agreement_lines)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/custom_addons/purchase_recurring_orders/models/recurring_orders.py", line 259, in create_order
    order_line_obj.create(order_line_vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/purchase/models/purchase.py", line 557, in create
    line = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self).create(values)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3830, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3987, in _create
    field.write(self.with_context(rel_context), vals[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 2402, in write
    link(act[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 2367, in link
    cr.execute(query, (records.ids, list(sub_ids), tuple(records.ids)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 231, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
•ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'account.tax'
```

So far I did not modify anything else than the group use.
This is the code of recurring_orders:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##############################################################################
#
#    Cybrosys Technologies Pvt. Ltd.
#    Copyright (C) 2009-TODAY Cybrosys Technologies(<http://www.cybrosys.com>).
#    Author: Jesni Banu(<http://www.cybrosys.com>)
#    you can modify it under the terms of the GNU LESSER
#    GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE (LGPL v3), Version 3.
#
#    It is forbidden to publish, distribute, sublicense, or sell copies
#    of the Software or modified copies of the Software.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE (LGPL v3) for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
#    GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE (LGPL v3) along with this program.
#    If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
###############################################################################
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from openerp import models, fields, api, exceptions, _
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT


class Agreement(models.Model):
    _name = 'purchase.recurring_orders.agreement'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _description = "Recurring orders agreement"

    @api.model
    def __get_next_term_date(self, date, unit, interval):
        if unit == 'days':
            return date + timedelta(days=interval)
        elif unit == 'weeks':
            return date + timedelta(weeks=interval)
        elif unit == 'months':
            return date + relativedelta(months=interval)
        elif unit == 'years':
            return date + relativedelta(years=interval)

    @api.multi
    def _compute_next_expiration_date(self):
        for agreement in self:
            if agreement.prolong == 'fixed':
                agreement.next_expiration_date = agreement.end_date
            elif agreement.prolong == 'unlimited':
                now = fields.Date.from_string(fields.Date.today())
                date = self.__get_next_term_date(
                    fields.Date.from_string(agreement.start_date),
                    agreement.prolong_unit, agreement.prolong_interval)
                while date < now:
                    date = self.__get_next_term_date(
                        date, agreement.prolong_unit,
                        agreement.prolong_interval)
                agreement.next_expiration_date = date
            else:
                agreement.next_expiration_date = self.__get_next_term_date(
                    fields.Date.from_string(agreement.last_renovation_date or
                                            agreement.start_date),
                    agreement.prolong_unit, agreement.prolong_interval)

    def _default_company_id(self):
        company_model = self.env['res.company']
        company_id = company_model._company_default_get('purchase')
        return company_model.browse(company_id.id)

    name = fields.Char(
        string='Name', size=100, index=True, required=True,
        help='Name that helps to identify the agreement')
    number = fields.Char(
        string='Agreement number', index=True, size=32, copy=False,
        help="Number of agreement. Keep empty to get the number assigned by a "
             "sequence.")
    active = fields.Boolean(
        string='Active', default=True,
        help='Unchecking this field, quotas are not generated')
    partner_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='res.partner', string='Supplier', index=True,
        change_default=True, required=True,
        help="Supplier you are making the agreement with")
    company_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='res.company', string='Company', required=True,
        help="Company that signs the agreement", default=_default_company_id)
    start_date = fields.Date(
        string='Start date', index=True, copy=False,
        help="Beginning of the agreement. Keep empty to use the current date")
    prolong = fields.Selection(
        selection=[('recurrent', 'Renewable fixed term'),
                   ('unlimited', 'Unlimited term'),
                   ('fixed', 'Fixed term')],
        string='Prolongation', default='unlimited',
        help="Sets the term of the agreement. 'Renewable fixed term': It sets "
             "a fixed term, but with possibility of manual renew; 'Unlimited "
             "term': Renew is made automatically; 'Fixed term': The term is "
             "fixed and there is no possibility to renew.", required=True)
    end_date = fields.Date(
        string='End date', help="End date of the agreement")
    prolong_interval = fields.Integer(
        string='Interval', default=1,
        help="Interval in time units to prolong the agreement until new "
             "renewable (that is automatic for unlimited term, manual for "
             "renewable fixed term).")
    prolong_unit = fields.Selection(
        selection=[('days', 'days'),
                   ('weeks', 'weeks'),
                   ('months', 'months'),
                   ('years', 'years')],
        string='Interval unit', default='years',
        help='Time unit for the prolongation interval')
    agreement_line = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='purchase.recurring_orders.agreement.line',
        inverse_name='agreement_id', string='Agreement lines')
    order_line = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='purchase.order', copy=False, inverse_name='agreement_id',
        string='Orders', readonly=True)
    renewal_line = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='purchase.recurring_orders.agreement.renewal', copy=False,
        inverse_name='agreement_id', string='Renewal lines', readonly=True)
    last_renovation_date = fields.Date(
        string='Last renovation date',
        help="Last date when agreement was renewed (same as start date if not "
             "renewed)")
    next_expiration_date = fields.Date(
        compute="_compute_next_expiration_date", string='Next expiration date')
    state = fields.Selection(
        selection=[('empty', 'Without orders'),
                   ('first', 'First order created'),
                   ('orders', 'With orders')],
        string='State', readonly=True, default='empty')
    renewal_state = fields.Selection(
        selection=[('not_renewed', 'Agreement not renewed'),
                   ('renewed', 'Agreement renewed')],
        string='Renewal state', readonly=True, default='not_renewed')
    notes = fields.Text('Notes')

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('number_uniq', 'unique(number)', 'Agreement number must be unique !'),
    ]

    @api.constrains('start_date', 'end_date')
    def _check_dates(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.end_date and record.end_date < record.start_date:
                raise exceptions.Warning(
                    _('Agreement end date must be greater than start date'))

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if not vals.get('start_date'):
            vals['start_date'] = fields.Date.today()
        if not vals.get('number'):
            vals['number'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].get(
                'purchase.r_o.agreement.sequence')
        return super(Agreement, self).create(vals)

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        value = super(Agreement, self).write(vals)
        if (any(vals.get(x) is not None for x in
                ['active', 'number', 'agreement_line', 'prolong', 'end_date',
                 'prolong_interval', 'prolong_unit', 'partner_id'])):
            self.unlink_orders(fields.Date.today())
        return value

    @api.model
    def copy(self, id, default=None):
        agreement_record = self.browse(id)
        default.update({
            'state': 'empty',
            'active': True,
            'name': '%s*' % agreement_record['name'],
        })
        return super(Agreement, self).copy(id, default=default)

    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        for agreement in self:
            if any(agreement.mapped('order_line')):
                raise exceptions.Warning(
                    _('You cannot remove agreements with confirmed orders!'))
        self.unlink_orders(fields.Date.from_string(fields.Date.today()))
        return models.Model.unlink(self)

    @api.multi
    def onchange_start_date(self, start_date=False):
        if not start_date:
            return {}
        result = {'value': {'last_renovation_date': start_date}}
        return result

    @api.model
    def revise_agreements_expirations_planned(self):
        for agreement in self.search([('prolong', '=', 'unlimited')]):
            if agreement.next_expiration_date <= fields.Date.today():
                agreement.write({'prolong': 'unlimited'})
        return True

    @api.model
    def _prepare_purchase_order_vals(self, agreement, date):
        order_vals = {
                        'date_order': date,
                        'date_confirm': date,
                        'origin': agreement.number,
                        'partner_id': agreement.partner_id.id,
                        'state': 'draft',
                        'company_id': agreement.company_id.id,
                        'from_agreement': True,
                        'agreement_id': agreement.id,
                        'location_id': 1,
                        'fiscal_position_id': self.env['account.fiscal.position'].with_context(company_id=agreement.company_id.id).get_fiscal_position(agreement.partner_id.id),
                        'payment_term_id': agreement.partner_id.property_supplier_payment_term_id.id,
                        'currency_id': agreement.partner_id.property_purchase_currency_id.id or self.env.user.company_id.currency_id.id,
                    }
        order_vals['user_id'] = agreement.partner_id.user_id.id
        return order_vals

    @api.model
    def _prepare_purchase_order_line_vals(self, agreement_line, order):
        product_lang = agreement_line.product_id.with_context({
            'lang': order.partner_id.lang,
            'partner_id': order.partner_id.id,
        })
        fpos = order.fiscal_position_id
        order_line_vals = {
            'order_id': order.id,
            'product_id': agreement_line.product_id.id,
            'product_qty': agreement_line.quantity,
            'date_planned': datetime.today().strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT),
            'price_unit': 0.0,
            'product_qty': 1.0,
            'product_uom': agreement_line.product_id.uom_po_id.id or agreement_line.product_id.uom_id.id,
            'name': product_lang.display_name,
            'taxes_id': fpos.map_tax(agreement_line.product_id.supplier_taxes_id.filtered(lambda r: r.company_id.id == self.company_id.id))
        }
        if agreement_line.specific_price:
            order_line_vals['price_unit'] = agreement_line.specific_price
        order_line_vals['taxes_id'] = [(6, 0, tuple(order_line_vals['taxes_id']))]
        if agreement_line.additional_description:
            order_line_vals['name'] += " %s" % (
                agreement_line.additional_description)
        return order_line_vals

    @api.multi
    def create_order(self, date, agreement_lines):
        self.ensure_one()
        order_line_obj = self.env['purchase.order.line'].with_context(
            company_id=self.company_id.id)
        order_vals = self._prepare_purchase_order_vals(self, date)
        order = self.env['purchase.order'].create(order_vals)
        for agreement_line in agreement_lines:
            order_line_vals = self._prepare_purchase_order_line_vals(
                agreement_line, order)
            order_line_obj.create(order_line_vals)
        agreement_lines.write({'last_order_date': fields.Date.today()})
        if self.state != 'orders':
            self.state = 'orders'
        return order

    @api.multi
    def _get_next_order_date(self, line, start_date):
        self.ensure_one()
        next_date = fields.Date.from_string(self.start_date)
        while next_date <= start_date:
            next_date = self.__get_next_term_date(
                next_date, line.ordering_unit, line.ordering_interval)
        return next_date

    @api.multi
    def generate_agreement_orders(self, start_date, end_date):
        self.ensure_one()
        if not self.active:
            return
        lines_to_order = {}
        exp_date = fields.Date.from_string(self.next_expiration_date)
        if exp_date < end_date and self.prolong != 'unlimited':
            end_date = exp_date
        for line in self.agreement_line:
            if not line.active_chk:
                continue
            next_order_date = self._get_next_order_date(line, start_date)
            while next_order_date <= end_date:
                if not lines_to_order.get(next_order_date):
                    lines_to_order[next_order_date] = self.env[
                        'purchase.recurring_orders.agreement.line']
                lines_to_order[next_order_date] |= line
                next_order_date = self._get_next_order_date(
                    line, next_order_date)
        dates = lines_to_order.keys()
        dates.sort()
        for date in dates:
            order = self.order_line.filtered(
                lambda x: (
                    fields.Date.to_string(
                        fields.Datetime.from_string(x.date_order)) ==
                    fields.Date.to_string(date)))
            if not order:
                self.create_order(
                    fields.Date.to_string(date), lines_to_order[date])

    @api.multi
    def generate_initial_order(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        agreement_lines = self.mapped('agreement_line').filtered('active_chk')
        order = self.create_order(self.start_date, agreement_lines)
        self.write({'state': 'first'})
        order.signal_workflow('order_confirm')
        return {
            'domain': "[('id', '=', %s)]" % order.id,
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'purchase.order',
            'context': self.env.context,
            'res_id': order.id,
            'view_id': [self.env.ref('purchase.purchase_order_form').id],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'nodestroy': True
        }

    @api.model
    def generate_next_orders_planned(self, years=1, start_date=None):
        if start_date:
            start_date = fields.Date.from_string(start_date)
        self.search([]).generate_next_orders(
            years=years, start_date=start_date)

    @api.multi
    def generate_next_year_orders(self):
        return self.generate_next_orders(years=1)

    @api.multi
    def generate_next_orders(self, years=1, start_date=None):
        if not start_date:
            start_date = fields.Date.from_string(fields.Date.today())
        end_date = start_date + relativedelta(years=years)
        for agreement in self:
            agreement.generate_agreement_orders(start_date, end_date)
        return True

    @api.model
    def confirm_current_orders_planned(self):
        tomorrow = fields.Date.to_string(
            fields.Date.from_string(fields.Date.today()) + timedelta(days=1))
        orders = self.env['purchase.order'].search([
            ('agreement_id', '!=', False),
            ('state', 'in', ('draft', 'sent')),
            ('date_order', '<', tomorrow)
        ])
        for order in orders:
            order.signal_workflow('order_confirm')

    @api.multi
    def unlink_orders(self, start_date):
        orders = self.mapped('order_line').filtered(
            lambda x: (x.state in ('draft', 'sent') and
                       x.date_order >= start_date))
        orders.unlink()


class AgreementLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'purchase.recurring_orders.agreement.line'

    uom_id = fields.Many2one('product_uom', string="Uom")
    active_chk = fields.Boolean(
        string='Active', default=True,
        help='Unchecking this field, this quota is not generated')
    agreement_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='purchase.recurring_orders.agreement',
        string='Agreement reference', ondelete='cascade')
    product_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='product.product', string='Product', ondelete='set null',
        required=True)
    name = fields.Char(
        related="product_id.name", string='Description', store=False)
    additional_description = fields.Char(
        string='Add. description', size=30,
        help='Additional description that will be added to the product '
             'description on orders.')
    quantity = fields.Float(
        string='Quantity', required=True, help='Quantity of the product',
        default=1.0)
    discount = fields.Float(string='Discount (%)', digits=(16, 2))
    ordering_interval = fields.Integer(
        string='Interval', required=True, default=1,
        help="Interval in time units for making an order of this product")
    ordering_unit = fields.Selection(
        selection=[('days', 'days'),
                   ('weeks', 'weeks'),
                   ('months', 'months'),
                   ('years', 'years')],
        string='Interval unit', required=True, default='months')
    last_order_date = fields.Date(
        string='Last order', help='Date of the last Purchase order generated')
    specific_price = fields.Float(
        string='Specific price', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Purchase Price'),
        help='Specific price for this product. Keep empty to use the list '
             'price while generating order')
    list_price = fields.Float(
        related='product_id.list_price', string="List price", readonly=True)

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('line_qty_zero', 'CHECK (quantity > 0)',
         'All product quantities must be greater than 0.\n'),
        ('line_interval_zero', 'CHECK (ordering_interval > 0)',
         'All ordering intervals must be greater than 0.\n'),
    ]

    @api.multi
    def onchange_product_id(self, product_id=False):
        result = {}
        if product_id:
            product = self.env['product.product'].browse(product_id)
            if product:
                result['value'] = {'name': product['name']}
        return result


class AgreementRenewal(models.Model):
    _name = 'purchase.recurring_orders.agreement.renewal'

    agreement_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='purchase.recurring_orders.agreement',
        string='Agreement reference', ondelete='cascade', select=True)
    date = fields.Date(string='Date', help="Date of the renewal")
    comments = fields.Char(
        string='Comments', size=200, help='Renewal comments')
```

I have found that this post might be relevant for this issue:
https://github.com/adhoc-dev/odoo-addons/issues/113

I have suspected that this line:

```py
'taxes_id': fpos.map_tax(agreement_line.product_id.supplier_taxes_id.filtered(lambda r: r.company_id.id == self.company_id.id))
```

might be the issue so I used a print statement:

```py
print fpos.map_tax(agreement_line.product_id.supplier_taxes_id.filtered(lambda r: r.company_id.id == self.company_id.id))
account.tax(6,)
```

But I do not know how to continue further.

Any help/tip on where the issue could be is welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code

```
fpos.map_tax(agreement_line.product_id.supplier_taxes_id.filtered(lambda r: r.company_id.id == self.company_id.id))
```

returns a recordset but database doesn't store record set. that's why it fails with the message.

> ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'account.tax'

**Solution**

```
recordset.id // for singleton recordset
result : id (integer)

recordset.ids // for multi recordset
result : list of ids []
```

now it depends on which type of field you are going to write this value. If it is a Many2one field then it is supposed to be an integer. that you may get with **recordset.id**

**NOTE 1** -

Be careful recordset can be recordsets that means mutliple records that will look like account.tax(6,7,12,34). In this case if you say recordset.id, it will fail because there are multiple Ids and it is not sure which one you want. So to get IDs from the recordset you can do **recordset.ids** that would result a list like [6,7,12,34] or [] in case a blank recordset.

**NOTE2 -**

If you were trying to write in a Many2many field. You can do something like

```
self.taxes_id = [(6,0, recordset.ids)]
```

Comment: Just adding .ids to the recordset made module work fine. 'taxes_id': fpos.map_tax(agreement_line.product_id.supplier_taxes_id.filtered(lambda r: r.company_id.id == self.company_id.id)).ids